# Python Scapy Arp Scanning Subnet Script From a Book

Tags: python, scapy

I am reading a Python book and in it there is a script to use scapy, the Python tool/module, to scan a subnet for any hosts that are up and report back their IP and MAC addresses. This script is an enhancement on a previous one that was calling `/usr/bin/arping`. That previous script only allowed one IP address at a time and was platform dependent on the `arping` tool being available. Apparently, this script (that does not work for me) is platform independent!

If someone could look over the script and debug it that would be awesome. Here is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import srp
from scapy.all import Ether, ARP, conf

import sys

def arping(iprange="10.0.1.0/24"):
    """Arping function takes IP Address or Network, returns nested mac/ip list"""

    #conf, verb = 0
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=iprange), timeout=2)

    collection = []
    for snd, rcv in ans:
        result = rcv.sprintf(r"%ARP.psrc% %Ether.src%").split()
        collection.append(result)
    return collection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for ip in sys.argv[1:]:
            print "arping", ip
            print arping(ip)

    else:
        print arping()
```

The script does not work. It just prints that it is scanning stuff but that nothing was found.

I looked on this website and found a tutorial that also did not work. That website with the relevant content is here: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#arp-ping

Please, see below for a sample of the output I obtain when running this script:

```
loser@loser:~/Desktop/pyFun2$ gedit arp_scanz.py
loser@loser:~/Desktop/pyFun2$ sudo python arp_scanz.py
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Begin emission:
Finished to send 256 packets.

Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 256 packets
[]
```

Does anyone out there know what I am missing?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**
change the srp function or method call to specify the exact interface to scan on like so:

```
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=iprange),iface="en1", timeout=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of things. I seem to have the script running just fine on my network using valid IP starting points.

Are you putting in a proper IP range?

For example I use:

```
def arping(iprange="192.168.1.*"):
```

which produces the correct results and identical results to scapy's built in arping() function.

So I think perhaps it's not the code exactly but the range you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks for testing this on your machine and offering some helpful advice. I found out that I had to specify the interface to scan on was my problem. I also found that using `arping()` method in an interactive shell does return the same results after opening the python interactive shell with the `sudo` command.I am not sure why this did not work last night. Maybe I needed to reboot my machine or maybe I was too tired and missing some small detail. See above for my call to `srp` now with specifying the interface to scan on. :D

Comment: It was not the range I was using but I did not realize this, scapy script, actually worked for anyone else. Thank-you for figuring this out and reporting back with your results. This was motivating...I found I could also specify I range using what I think is called CIDR notation like so `192.168.1.0/24` This will scan everything in the subnet just like `192.168.1.*` :D